# ssh detach remote command with pseudo terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal, nohup

i am running videos on raspberryPi+bigMonitor few meters from me with command:

```
ssh    pi 'omxplayer file.mp4 </dev/null &>/dev/null &'
```

that works great.

But if i want to use ssh's virtual terminal allocation `-t` that command do not works anymore.

I really need `-t` for using great ncurses based video menu with 'fzf' before omxplayer, but all of my specific problems are not important, because main problem can be simulated with `sleep 10` instead of omxplayer:

on remote computer:

```
watch -n1 'ps aux | grep [s]leep\ 10'   #monitoring if 'sleep' running.
```

on local computer various tests:

```
ssh -t pi 'sleep 10 </dev/null &>/dev/null &'                  #not working
ssh -t pi 'nohup  sleep 10 </dev/null &>/dev/null & disown'    #not working
ssh -t pi 'setsid sleep 10 </dev/null &>/dev/null &'           #not working
ssh -t pi 'nohup  sleep 10 </dev/null &>/dev/null & sleep 0'   #works OK !!!!
ssh -t pi 'setsid sleep 10 </dev/null &>/dev/null & sleep 0'   #works OK
ssh -t pi 'nohup  sleep 10 </dev/null &>/dev/null & /bin/true' #not working
ssh -t pi 'nohup  sleep 10 </dev/null &>/dev/null & (true & wait)' #works ok
```

'sleep 0' in the end is probably the best solution, proposed by @egmont.

Still wondering if there is some better, more reliable solution, and what was exact cause for this (probably ssh closing vt is too fast for parallel nohup/setsid run).

Comment: I see from your edits that you have already considered tmux or screen. What is the relation between fzf and your problem?

Comment: @icarus this commands are simplified situation of real scripts where i reached this problem, and where i used fzf. fzf over ssh needs virtual terminal 'ssh -t', and this problem will reach anyone who for some reason uses '-t' and have no commands after detaching.

Comment: The discussion at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1429938 perhaps gives you some clues. I'm not sure if ssh cares whether the child process it launched finishes, but it definitely cares about the 3 standard file descriptors still being open or getting closed. If you just execute a single command then bash optimizes it to be an "exec", closing its 3 standard FDs and _then_ replacing itself with omxplayer or nohup, which might be too late. If you have that "sleep" then bash cannot do this optimization, hence it'll close _its_ FDs only after executing omxplayer or nohup...

Comment: ... so try replacing that "sleep 0.1" with "sleep 0" or "/bin/true", my guess is that it'll also work.

Comment: @egmont 'sleep 0' cool idea, tested now, it works :) ... /bin/true will be beter but it not works, simple 'ls' works too, and '(true & wait) works too. comparing to c programming, command must wait for something (allowing other thread execution)... but sleep 0 seems the best for now.

Comment: I don't know what could be the difference between "/bin/true" and "sleep 0". Maybe my theory doesn't hold, and "sleep" just takes a tiny bit more time to start up making it happen to work for you.

Comment: @icarus, fzf is great menu but i want to solve all my future '-t' problems. i tested disown last night, not worked, setsid also not works (but i will try with that extra params for disown now).

Comment: @egmont instead omxplayer i put sleep 10 now, and it is easy to test with '"watch ps aux | grep sleep"'on other side. same results always, sleep 0 works and /bin/true not... actually maybe just once it worked too but 99% tries not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the background shell that will turn into nohup to run sleep or omxplayer is getting a SIGHUP before it has turned into nohup and set the signal handler to ignore.

```
ssh -t pi 'trap HUP "" ; omxplayer file.mp4 </dev/null &>/dev/null &'
```

works for me every time, whilst some of the other approaches like `sleep 0` sometimes fail.

Comment: respect, you solve it the best way. btw "" before hup, working well in my scripts.