# ssh execute remote script

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, gstreamer

I've an application on my machine that is working with a remote one. Before I'm able to use this app, I need to run some commands on the remote one. Here for I've created an script named `startUpRun.sh`. In this script there are some commands for a gstreamer connection like

`gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,channels=1,rate=16000 ! audioconvert ! rtpL16pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.1 port=5555 &`

When I execute the script during an ssh session on the remote machine this works completely fine for me and this script does what it should do.

But when I invoke this script by executing it from my machine using

```
 sshpass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t root@192.168.1.2 "source ./startUpRun.sh"
```

but unfortunately no gstreamer instance gets started. I've checked this multiple times using `pgrep gst` and `top`.

Does somebody have an idea what I probably missed?

Comment: did you try 'source ./startUpRun.sh </dev/null &>/dev/null'

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for me neither..

Comment: than 'nohup source /full/path/of/script/startUpRn.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1' ... should work.

Comment: unfortunately, this works also not.. :-/

Comment: what is the absolute for your script on the remote machine ?

Comment: the absolute path of my script is `/root/startUpRun.sh`

Comment: maybe with sleep 'nohup source /full/path/of/script/startUpRn.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1; sleep 1' . but if this also fails, you should remove detaching   '&' from inside script and do it inside ssh command. and chmod 755 without 'source'-ing to simplify things... sshpass removing if possible too... good luck

Comment: ... i realized now that you also used '-t' pseudo terminal, so i think that we both asked nearly the same question inside 15 minutes :) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326494/ssh-detach-remote-command-with-pseudo-terminal (my temporary solution is with sleep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the & from the end of the line, so that the connection stays up. You can use ssh parameters to bring the session to the background instead